# CSS3 - Prevent popup body from growing by its content

Tags: html, css, popup

I am coding a popup same as the following picture:

[image]

And this is my css code example.

```css
html,
body {
  height : 100%;
}

#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  bottom : 0;
  left : 0;
  right : 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal-box {
  height : 100%;
  width : 400px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left : auto;
  display : table;
  table-layout : fixed;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-body,
.modal-footer {
  display : table-row;
}

.modal-body {
  height : 100%;
}

.body-content {
  display : table-cell;
  vertical-align : middle;
  height : 100%;
  overflow : auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <header>
    <title>Test Modal</title>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div id="modal">
      <div class="modal-box">
        <div class="modal-header">Header</div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="body-content">
            <div class="txt">This is body content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I try test the scroll when body gets over height, the body keeps growing by it's content.

I tested with above css:

```
.modal-body .txt {
   height : 1000px;
}
```

I need to find a way to keep the body height fixed while header and footer will grow by it's content.

I did try with flex css, but the result is the same with above code.

Comment: Have you tried using max-height?

Comment: @Roy which element should I put max-height? and set max-height : 100%; ?

Comment: ```#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 500px;
}


.modal-body{
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}```  Try this. If this is what you need.

Comment: You're using many table-related css attributes and styles, but you're not using a `<table>` here. Is there a reason for that? Using such styles has been a useful hack in the past, but as far as I know isn't needed anymore.  Those could be introducing unexpected behavior; at minimum, they could be confusing for developers who work on your code in future.  (Maybe there's a legit reason to still use values like these; could be - I'm not aware of one though.)

Comment: @PrakharMittal I need modal-body to take all remaining space while header and footer will grow by it's content.

Comment: @avocadatoria I use table css for many projects, and I think it's still usefull anw. one thing im pretty sure that it works well for Cross-browser compatibility

Comment: Check this out and let me know if this works: https://jsfiddle.net/prak_mtl/3qfzvdw2/4/